# The html doesn't seem to be able to read the script element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code is trying to change a paragraph element in the html, but nothing in the script element seems to even be recognized

We have tried many different variations of this code to try to understand what isn't working, but nothing in the script element is even recognized

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <h3>Final Schedule</h3>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id ="fs">hi2</p>
        <input id="request" type="button" value="Get Final Schedule">

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                console.log("hi");
                $("#request").click(requestClicked);
                console.log("done2");
            });

            console.log("h")
            function requestClicked(){
                $("#fs").html("ohafhiohfos");
                console.log("done");
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want the code to change the paragraph element to something else, but nothing is working, and the console.log()'s aren't working at all

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Side note, you can't have `<h3>` in the head.

Comment: If the script element has `src` attribute, all the content between the tags is ignored.

Comment: `script` element with `src` cannot have content and `script` with content cannot have `src`

Comment: I see you're using the `src` attribute, but you're also supplying written code in the body of the element. You have to choose one or the other. This will require two `script` elements.

Answer (score 4):

You can't put your code inside the script element for `jQuery`. Instead add another script tag below it with your code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <h3>Final Schedule</h3>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id ="fs">hi2</p>
        <input id="request" type="button" value="Get Final Schedule">

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
                console.log("hi");
                $("#request").click(requestClicked);
                console.log("done2");
            });

            console.log("h")
            function requestClicked(){
                $("#fs").html("ohafhiohfos");
                console.log("done");
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

A script tag can't have both `src` and internal text code. You need two tags

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            console.log("hi");
            $("#request").click(requestClicked);
            console.log("done2");
        });

        console.log("h")
        function requestClicked(){
            $("#fs").html("ohafhiohfos");
            console.log("done");
        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need 2 script tags, 1 to list the jquery library you're using and 1 to write the actual code

Answer (score 1):

Try making one `<script>` tag for jQuery (`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>`) and another one for your code:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                console.log("hi");
                $("#request").click(requestClicked);
                console.log("done2");
            });

            console.log("h")
            function requestClicked(){
                $("#fs").html("ohafhiohfos");
                console.log("done");
            };
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You are using a rather old version of jQuery and might want to update to a more recent one
2. A script tag can either have an src attribute, requiring a script file, OR script content directly, not both. So just make a second script block with the code you'd like to execute:

```html
        <p id ="fs">hi2</p>
        <input id="request" type="button" value="Get Final Schedule">

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                console.log("hi");
                $("#request").click(requestClicked);
                console.log("done2");
            });

            console.log("h")
            function requestClicked(){
                $("#fs").html("ohafhiohfos");
                console.log("done");
            };
        </script>
```